# How to recognise mouseDragged and mousePressed events in one listener?

Tags: java, swing, mouse, listener

In following code, mouseDragged is not recognized. What do I do wrong?

```
addMouseListener(new MouseInputAdapter() {

  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { ... }
  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { ... }

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
MouseInputAdapter mia = new MouseInputAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { ... }
  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { ... }
};
addMouseListener(mia);
addMouseMotionListener(mia); // <-- You're missing this one.
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not recognized because you are implementing `mouseDragged` inside of an `addMouseListener`.

`mouseDragged` is triggered by a [**`MouseMotionListener`**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) and `mousePressed` is triggered by a [**`MouseListener`**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Therefore you need to implement both `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` and add the right listener accordingly.

```
public class MyClass extends JPanel implements MouseListener,
                                               MouseMotionListener {

  public MyClass() {
    // whatever code you need, then add the listeners
    this.addMouseListener(this); 
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
   }

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { ... }
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { ... }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use addMouseListener, but addMouseMotionListener :

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

:D

Comment: This I tried before I came here to ask, but it doesn't work, for the reasons mentioned by Anthony Forloney.